# Is there a better way to do SELECT queries in MySQL and sort them in PHP than this way?

Tags: php, mysql

I am just learning PHP/MySQL, one this I am having to do a lot is displaying data that was previously inserted into the database out to the user's browser. So I am doing this:

```
$select = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM pages');

while ($return = mysql_fetch_assoc($select))
{
     $title = $return['title'];
     $author = $return['author'];
     $content = $return['content'];
}
```

then I can use these variables through out the page. Now, doing it the above way isn't an issue when I only have 3 columns in a database but what if I am dealing with a huge database with many more columns.

I have a nagging feeling that the pros do it in some more efficient way where they maybe loop through the table they are selecting from to find all columns it has and associate them with variables automatically. Is that the case? or is the above how you guys do it too?

### EDIT

Thanks for the answers guys, they have helped me to explain what I had in mind better. The reason why I am trying to do this, is so that I have to write less.

Is it possible to get the names of the columns of a table automatically. Then have a loop that will automatically create the variables naming them the same as the column names:

```
some type of loop 
{

   $nameofcolumn = $return['$nameofcolumn'];

}
```

This way I don't have to manually repeat myself:

```
 $title = $return['title'];
 $author = $return['author'];
 $content = $return['content'];
```

Because normally I just name the variables the same as the table column names.

Comment: My answer does exactly what your edit describes :)

Comment: Why would you want to do this? i would just use `$return['title']` and the like directly from the array returned.

Comment: You should be able to sort the results by adding an `ORDER BY COL_NAME` to your query... however you'll also likely want to limit your query to only return the top 100? or however many results... if this table starts to grow.  You should also list the columns you want to return rather than use `*`... esp when you get columns with huge amounts of data.

Comment: Don't assign something you can already access to a second name. It's a waste of code and a waste of memory. When you need to use the title, use `$return['title']`, don't assign that to `$title` then use `$title`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out `extract` would be better than my initial solution:

```
$select = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM pages');

while ($return = mysql_fetch_assoc($select))
{
     extract($return, EXTR_OVERWRITE);
}
```

Both solutions will overwrite any already existing variables with the name of a column though.

But I am not quite getting why anyone would want to do that.
I must say that I understand what you are trying to do, but not why :D

Comment: @x3ro I was thinking of giving this answer, but then thought that it wouldn't make an inkling of sense because if there was more than one row in the DB (as implied by the `while` statement), then only the last row's values would be stored in the new variables.

Comment: Yep, thats why I wrote the last line. But then I thought, maybe he's doing a lot more stuff in that while loop that he's actually showing us, where he would like to use those variables (so just shortening stuff for convenience). *confused*

Comment: @x3ro Also, just as a sidenote, instead of the inner `foreach` loop, I'd just use `extract` :P

Comment: I actually didn't know about extract :) Thank you.

Comment: @x3ro when I echoed $title or $author inside the while loop it didn't output anything. If your code does what I was describing, shouldn't it assign the column values to variables with the same names? thanks for bearing with this noob :)

Comment: @x3ro it didn't refresh for me when you made the edit. The 2nd part of your code does exactly what I was describing.

Answer (score 0):

Might be off topic but consider to learn MySQL using PDO extension as it would help you to avoid common mistakes and would help you to migrate to more complex solutions like Zend_DB, Doctrine or Propel